# Как установить права на новые создаваемые файлы и папки?

Tags: linux, debian, samba

Linux Debian. Samba 4. Linux, Samba не в домене и не являются контроллером. Это обычный компьютер.

Расшаренная папка - Exchange.
Группа group1, пользователи входящие в группу user1, user2..user5.

Права на папку Exchange
drwxrwx--- 5 root  group1 4096 Мар 22 11:04 Exchange

Часть конфига smb.conf

```
[Exchange]
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
path = /home/Shared_files/Exchange
comment = No comment
valid users = user1 user2 user3 user4 user5
write list = user1 user2 user3 user4 user5
force group = group1
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no
```

Папка расшарена на Линуксе, к ней из Windows подключаются пользователи, вводя логин и пароль. Попадают в папку и создают там файлы, папки. Т.е. из проводника windows ->правая кнопка мыши->создать.

Проблема в том, что полными правами (удаление, редактирование и т.д.) на созданный файл или папку обладает его создатель. А все остальные пользователи - только чтение.

Как сделать так, чтобы полные права на созданные файлы и папки в папке Exchange были у всех пользователей группы group1? Своеобразная "файловая помойка" для группы group1.

Comment: Попробуй `create mask = 0664`

Comment: Сделал. Спасибо. Стало лучше.


Разрешения файла для группы-group1 из чтения стало чтение, запись.


Сейчас любой пользователь group1 может изменять файл, копировать его. Изменять имя папки, созданной другим пользователем.


Но не может удалить папку или файл созданный другим пользователем. И не может изменить имя файла.
Имя папки изменить может.

Comment: Судя по всему файлы могут создаваться в обход самба. Тогда вам нужен стики-бит группы на папки, чтобы вновь создаваемые в них файлы принадлежали общей группе, а не личной группе создателя этих файлов. `chmod g+s ...`

Comment: Вы правы, но стик бит уже есть.
Сработало это.
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 2777
Но так и не пойму, что за магия тут написана и как оно работает.
Похоже маски - это отдельная тема и 0644 не связано с chmod 644 - т.е. правами на папки в Линукс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это сработало.

Нужно поставить стики бит на папку

chmod g+s /home/Shared_files

И в конфиге самбы, для этой папки прописать

```
[Exchange]
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 2777
```

Теперь кто угодно из группы может делать что угодно в этой папке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте зайти на шару из под windows с правами администратора и в свойствах папки уже выставить права наследования. Т.е. нажимаете на папку ПКМ и в свойствах во вкладке безопасность выставляете права, а так же там есть права наследования.

Comment: Так не может даже быть в силу - различия прав систем виндовс и линукс, контролем прав самбой. И это ещё не учитывая наследование прав.